# ParallelOptions.CancellationToken seems useless

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, task-parallel-library

One of the members of the ParallelOptions is CancellationToken, the value of which is meant to be accessed within the lambda function of Parallel.ForEach.

Using it requires instantiating a CacellationToken before invoking Parallel.ForEach so why can't that local variable be accessed directly within the Lambda function of the ForEach?

e.g. instead of:

```
var ct = new CancellationToken();
var options = new ParallelOptions { CancellationToken = ct }

Parallel.ForEach(source, options, (item) =>
{
     options.ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
})
```

why can't I just use:

```
var ct = new CancellationToken();

Parallel.ForEach(source, (item) =>
{
     ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
})
```

Is it just a convenient place to stash the token, or is there some underlying reason for this design?

Comment: What's nice about ParallelOptions is that you *don't* have to check the cancellation token yourself.  Parallel already does it for you.  So, no, it isn't useless :)

Comment: @HansPassant - you're right, as Jon answered below. I didn't assume so because the MSDN documentation showed an explicit check for cancellation even though it is unecessary (as you say) - the example they give does the check right at the end of the loop, making it redundant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you tell `Parallel.ForEach` about the `CancellationToken`, it can stop processing when the token is cancelled. You may not want to throw an exception from your loop - you may just want to ignore the cancellation token yourself, and just expect that a subset of your items will be processed.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
        var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList();
        Parallel.ForEach(items, new ParallelOptions { CancellationToken = cts.Token },
            item =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            });
    }
}
```

This will finish after three seconds with an `OperationCanceledException` (rather than the `AggregateException` you'd receive if one/some of the individual tasks failed) - but the action body itself doesn't need to know about a cancellation token. Sure, if you have an expensive operation which you don't want to complete unnecessarily for the final items being processed you *can* monitor the token yourself, but otherwise you can just let `Parallel.ForEach` notice and throw the exception itself.

Comment: Is that really true? The ForEach watches for CancellationRequested and does the equivalent of ThrowIfCancellationRequested without telling you? The MSDN example for cancelling a ForEach (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256691(v=vs.110).aspx) uses an explicit ThrowIfCancellationRequested withing the loop - you're saying it's redundant?

Comment: @afuna: Not necessarily redundant - if your action body does multiple things and you want to stop between them if cancellation has been requested, then you *may* want to monitor it - but you don't *have* to, as I've shown in my example.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The documentation is a bit missing on this. However, there is one other difference I noticed after rereading MSDN - the token will throw a direct OperationCancelled exception as apposed to an AggregateException. Do you care to add that tidbit to your answer, and I'll mark it as accepted?

Comment: @afuna: Done. (In the final paragraph.)

Answer (score -3):

"Jon Skeet"'s answer is not true for all scenarios. 
The Cancellation of token source, that comes from ParallelOptions, does not break Parallel.ForEach loop until all tasks finished.
To break the loop you must use, for example, call to token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(), or to finish all tasks.

Comment: He addresses that in the last paragraph: "Sure, if you have an expensive operation which you don't want to complete unnecessarily for the final items being processed you can monitor the token yourself, ..."

Comment: Additionally, if you want to leave a comment on an answer you should use the commenting system (though it appears you may not have enough reputation yet to do so), but if you intend to leave an answer, you need to leave a complete answer, not a comment about another answer.